# Need to add $_GET args to my regex

Tags: regex, lighttpd

```
    url.rewrite-once = (
    ".*\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html)$" => "$0",
    "^/([^?]*)(\?.*)?$" => "/$1.php/$2",
)
```

This is what I got but the args don't work.
I like following url

```
http://www.example.com/index.php/?r=something
```

To look like this:

```
http://www.example.com/index/?r=something
```

Thanx

Comment: Maybe: <br /> "^/([^\?]*)(\?.*)?$" => "/$1.php/$2",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `/index/?r=something` is requested, it is rewritten to `/index/.php/?r=something`. So try this rule:

```
"^/([^?]*[^?/])/?(\?.*)?$" => "/$1.php/$2"
```

With this pattern the trailing slash is optional.